# Autonomous car simulator with ROS bridge

Tags: ros-lunar, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been working on Autonomous car project and looking for simulator.
Could you please suggest me simulators which has inbuilt `rosbridge` configured.
Currently I am using Carla simulator, but it is bit complex. I am looking for a simple and basic one.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314545/autonomous-car-simulator-with-ros-bridge/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2019-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-02-05**:
@ahendrix Thanks for the input. As of now I am looking for a simple simulator with decent features so that I can test some of the basic algorithms. Later I can plan big and go for a simulator like Carla, Airsim etc which has better features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Autonomous cars are not simple projects, and any good simulation will take into account a lot of factors. I suggest you do a bit of research to choose a good simulator, and then learn to use it well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0